# Could centrifugal force save this scene in movie "Gravity"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

The [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYDaIyfitn8) on movie "Gravity" where George Clooney dies has taken a lot of heat, and I could not find one single person able to defend it, as physics is concerned. There is even an [interview with an astronaut](https://www.vulture.com/2013/10/astronaut-fact-checks-gravity.html) that said he couldn't understand the scene.

When I first watched the movie, I thought: "well, there must be some plausible explanation, since realistic inertia is an important plot element", so I dismissed the issue believing there was some angular momentum creating a centrifugal force that could make the scene work. But the lack of any mention of it on the internet prompted me to ask it here:

1. is it plausible that they ended up with a small angular speed, as briefly seen in a shot, after being caught in the cables?
2. would the centrifugal force be strong enough to justify the astronaut's action?

Answer (score 0):

This movie scene simply doesn't make any sense. Both are moving through space at the same speed in the same direction so when George Clooney lets go he wouldn't be moving away from the lady any quicker.

In the scene, it looks like there was some angular momentum at first, but then it magically stops. Let's say there was an angular velocity. In that case, it would make sense that Clooney would move away when he untethers because there would be a linear force acting on him. That being said it wouldn't make sense for him to let go because he could get back to the station by pulling on the rope.